# How to run two PostGIS versions in parallel on Windows?

Tags: postgis, postgis-2.0, windows, update

I'm trying to understand how to install PostGIS2.0 on Windows7. The PostGIS [site](http://www.postgis.org/download/windows/experimental.php) has the following suggestions:

> PostGIS Experimental Binaries PostGIS 2.0.0SVN Binaries with Raster,
>   Topology support + Extras (Tiger Geocoder 2010) As of November 25th,
>   2011 (r8242) includes GEOS 3.3.2dev r3516, Proj 4.6.1, JSON-c 0.9,
>   libgdal 1.9 SVN r23320 (VERSIONS prior to (r7923) require a dump
>   reload since operators have changed. We now have the 3D spatial
>   indexes, 3D box operators, KNN GIST for 9.1, and 2 raster map algebra)
>
> More details about what has been fixed/added can be found at PostGIS
>   2.0.0 and PostGIS 1.5.3/1.5.4 fixes , What is new in PostGIS 2.0, PostGIS Raster support, and improved Topology support These are 32-bit
>   binaries so will not work on 64-bit PostgreSQL. We are working on
>   getting 64-bit binaries out as well, but are running into some
>   stumbling blocks. For the time being -- if you are on Windows 64-bit,
>   you must install the 32-bit PostgreSQL to use these.
>
> ```
> For PostgreSQL 8.4 w/ Loader/Dumper including GUI
> For PostgreSQL 9.0 (compiled against PostgreSQL 9.0.3) w/ Loader/Dumper including GUI
> For PostgreSQL 9.1 (compiled against PostgreSQL 9.1.0 - note 9.1 structure changed in beta 1 so this will not work with alpha releases
> ```
>
> but should be fine for all beta, release candidate releases and final
>   9.1.0 release) w/ Loader/Dumper including GUI. Also includes extensions files to install using new PostgreSQL 9.1+ CREATE EXTENSION
>   syntax. To install:
>
> ```
> First copy the share/extension files into your PostgreSQL share/extension folder.
>
> Then in any database you'd like to spatially enable, run at least postgis (which contains both geometry and raster support) and
> ```
>
> optionally postgis_topology commands.
>
> ```
> CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
> CREATE EXTENSION postgis_topology;
> ```

I currently have PostGIS 1.5 installed on PostgreSQL 8.4. This is what my folder structure looks like:

[image]

I don't fully understand these instructions:

> First copy the share/extension files into your PostgreSQL
>   share/extension folder.
>
> Then in any database you'd like to spatially enable, run at least
>   postgis (which contains both geometry and raster support) and
>   optionally postgis_topology commands.

I've downloaded `postgisgui_pgadmin-2.0.0svn` and `postgis-pg84-binaries-2.0.0svn`. In my original folder structure I don't have a folder `extension` within `share`. Do I just copy the contents of `postgis-pg84-binaries-2.0.0svn` into this folder? What does it mean to `run at least postgis`? I've also tried to follow the detailed instructions at the following [blog](http://libregis.org/2011/03/10/how-to-install-and-configure-postgis-raster-on-windows/).

---

EDIT: I have installed Postgresql 9.1 with PostGIS 1.5.3. I am trying to figure out where to copy the PostGIS 2.0 binaries. It seems like I should be copying them into the folders here:

[image]

but the advice suggests placing them in the share/extension folder.

I tried copying the entire folder into `share/extension/` and then editing the `makepostgis.bat` file to make it relevant to my file system (the port is 5434 as I have two instances of Postgresql running).

```
set PGPORT=5434 
set PGHOST=localhost
set PGUSER=postgres
set PGPASSWORD=****
set THEDB=template_postgis20
set PGBIN=C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.1\bin\
set PGLIB=C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.1\lib\
```

When I run this file as an administrator, I get the following error:

```
C:\Windows\system32>set PGPORT=5434    
C:\Windows\system32>set PGHOST=localhost    
C:\Windows\system32>set PGUSER=postgres    
C:\Windows\system32>set PGPASSWORD=****    
C:\Windows\system32>set THEDB=template_postgis20    
C:\Windows\system32>set PGBIN=C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.1\bin\    
C:\Windows\system32>set PGLIB=C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.1\lib\    
C:\Windows\system32>set POSTGISVER=2.0    
C:\Windows\system32>xcopy bin\*.* "C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.1\bin\"
File not found - *.*
0 File(s) copied

C:\Windows\system32>xcopy /I /S bin\postgisgui\* "C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.1\bin\\postgisgui"
File not found - *
0 File(s) copied

C:\Windows\system32>xcopy lib\*.* "C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.1\lib\"
File not found - *.*
0 File(s) copied

C:\Windows\system32>"C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.1\bin\\psql"  -c "CREATE DATABASE template_postgis20"
ERROR:  database "template_postgis20" already exists

C:\Windows\system32>"C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.1\bin\\psql"  -d "template_postgis20" -c "CREATE LANGUAGE plpgs
ql"
ERROR:  language "plpgsql" already exists

C:\Windows\system32>"C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.1\bin\\psql"  -d "template_postgis20" -f "share\contrib\postgis
-2.0\postgis.sql"
share/contrib/postgis-2.0/postgis.sql: No such file or directory

....the errors continue....
```

Comment: @underdark, I think it is wrong to say this is about upgrading. It is about installing PotGIS 2.0 as they can live together in the db-cluster. In a specific database they cannot and I guess that is not the intention in the question, but to install PostGIS 2.0 in a new database.

Comment: @Nicklas Originally, I was intending to install PostGIS2.0 in the same cluster. Can I have several Postgresql instances on the same computer? It seems like it would be easier to install both; so long as they don't interfer with the current installation.

Comment: So the question would be how to run two versions in parallel?

Comment: I think it is now. I want to have both 1.5.3 and 2.0 running; I didn't realize they need to be on separate postgresql servers.

Comment: no, not on different servers. just different databases

Comment: Why not create a virtual machine and put one of the versions on that? If Windows licensing is an issue you could set it up on Linux.

Comment: I don't have a problem with the postgresql installations, just figuring out how to install postgis2.0. The question is now a bit muddled as I updated it along the way, perhaps I should rephrase it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've updated the instructions on the website.  Hope it's a bit clearer.

Nicklas is right you don't really need the makepostgis.bat if you just copy the like folders to your postgresql install  (you could also remark out the create db in it since it does copy all the files).  You should be able to just overlay ontop since the zip structure is the same as standard windows enterprisedb packaged PostgreSQL binaries.  What I neglected to mention in the instructions is that you do still need the binaries and libs.  This I have updated so its should be clearer.

We don't have the create extension approach as the official for PostgreSQL 9.1 yet since we are working out some issues with using the ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPGRADE .. syntax
which is more of an issue with PostGIS 2.0 non-released since there are no official freeze points yet.  In the currently packaged it works fine but its harder to ensure it works given all the flux of stuff going on in PostGIS 2.0 in the past month.

Comment: Thanks @LR1234567 I've tried copying everything into the respective folders on my Postgresql 9.1 installation. When I create a db in postgresql (choosing template postgis2.0); I get an error when I run `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;` The error is: `ERROR:  type "spheroid" already exists, SQL state: 42710`

Comment: Celenius, I think your issue is your are trying to create a template postgis 20 with functions already installed and then trying to do CREATE EXTENSION.. You do one or the other not both.  So create a fresh postgresql database -- don't install any postgis functions.  Then in that db do CREATE EXTENSION ....   In the next release -- we'll include a separate batch script that does the create extension stuff so hopefully it will be clearer.

Comment: Thanks @LR1234567, running `CREATE etc...` by itself appeared to work. I was able to load a shapefile into that database and am currently trying to load a raster. I'm finding your book very helpful too.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**:

The reason that you don't have the extension folder is that you are not on PostgreSQL 9.1 when the extension feature was introduced.

What you should do is put the binaries in the bin-folder as described in the beginning of the readme-file.

Then running postgis means that you are supposed to run the sql-code in the file postgis.sql to install the types and functions in PostGIS into the database. To install raster and topology you will also have to run thosose files.

You can read about that in the installation part of the doc.

/Nicklas

Comment: Hi @Nicklas I just updated my question (and Postgresql to 9.1). I did read the `readme` but I'm still not clear on where to copy the binaries.

Comment: ok, if you have upgraded to PostgreSQL 9.1 you should have that extension folder in the share folder in the 9.1 folder and follow that part of the instructions. I have not installed 2.0 in windows myself.

Comment: I do have the `share/extension` folder in `9.1`. Do I copy everything from the postgis binary folder into `share/extension`?. The instructions are not clear about what files to copy, or where to copy them.

Comment: extensions is a new feature in 9.1. the thing is that an extensuon is installed with the "create extension" command. I don't think makepostgis.bat is relevant if you go the extension road, but I am not sure.